# Fix Pygame player input response time

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pygame, controls

(Sorry if this question is hard to understand, this is my first question. I am happy to clarify anything that needs to be clarified. Thanks in advance)

I am working on a simple [2048 game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2048_(video_game)). And so far it seems to be going great, the issue I believe I am having is that my code is zooming over my `control` function so quickly that it isn't updating the list. The list starts out as:
`['none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none']`

But when you press a button, the list doesn't update. I have tried tweaking the `control` function code, but I haven't been able to make any headway.

```
import pygame
import sys
import random

pygame.init()
fps = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_size = screen_width, screen_height = 800, 800
display = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)

game_state = ['none', 'none', 'none', 'none',
              'none', 'none', 'none', 'none',
              'none', 'none', 'none', 'none',
              'none', 'none', 'none', 'none']

class game_func:
    def __init__(self):
        self.input = False
        self.count = 0

    def controls(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self.input = True

    def random(self):
        var = random.randrange(0, 16)
        if game_state[var] == 'none':
            return var
        else:
            self.random()

    def spawn(self):
        if self.input:
            pos = self.random()
            if random.randrange(0, 2) == 1:
                num = 'two'
            else:
                num = 'four'
            game_state[pos] = num
            self.input = False

    def blit(self):
        x, y = 0, 0

        idx = self.count
        pos = game_state[idx]

        if 0 < idx < 4:
            y = 0
            x = idx
        elif 3 < idx < 8:
            y = 200
            x = idx - 4
        elif 7 < idx < 12:
            y = 400
            x = idx - 8
        elif 11 < idx < 16:
            y = 600
            x = idx - 12
        x *= 200
        cord = x, y
        print(idx)
        print(cord)
        print(game_state)

        self.count += 1
        if self.count == 16:
            self.count = 0

def end():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def main():
    game = game_func()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                end()
        game.blit()
        game.controls()
        game.spawn()
        pygame.display.update()
        fps.tick(30)


main()
end()
```

Comment: Taking out all those `print` calls would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame never has any events for the `game.controls()` function, because they're all being consumed by the clause in the main loop.

```
def main():
    game = game_func()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():    # CONSUME EVERY EVENT
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                end()
        game.blit()
        game.controls()  # NO EVENTS LEFT FOR THIS
```

Maybe if the event is not `pygame.QUIT`, *then* pass it to `game.controls()`.  For example:

```
def main():
    game = game_func()
    while True:
        game.blit()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                end()
            else:
                game.controls( event )
```

And controls is:

```
class game_func:

    ...

    def controls(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            self.input = True
```

Comment: Thank you so~ much!!!! I feel kinda stupid now, but hey, live and let learn. Thank you very much!